# Building a VM using Ansible Tower and I want to have the ability to create additional disks only when their variables are defined

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I'm currently building Ansible image playbook templates across AWS and VSphere and I'd like be able to define multiple additional disks but only when they're defined via the variables.

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:

  - name: Launch Windows 2016 VM Instance
    vmware_guest:
      validate_certs: no
      datacenter: "{{ vm_datacenter }}"
      folder: "{{ vm_folder }}"
      name: "{{ vm_servername }}"
      state: poweredon
      template: "{{ vm_template }}"
      cluster: "{{ vm_cluster }}"
      disk:
       - size_gb: "{{ vm_disk_size0 | default(80) }}"
         type: "{{ vm_disk_type0 | default(thin) }}"
         datastore: "{{ vm_disk_datastore0 }}"
       - size_gb: "{{ vm_disk_size1 }}"
         type: "{{ vm_disk_type1 }}"
         datastore: "{{ vm_disk_datastore1 }}"
       - size_gb: "{{ vm_disk_size2 }}"
         type: "{{ vm_disk_type2 }}"
         datastore: "{{ vm_disk_datastore2 }}"
       - size_gb: "{{ vm_disk_size3 }}"
         type: "{{ vm_disk_type3 }}"
         datastore: "{{ vm_disk_datastore3 }}"
      hardware:
        memory_mb: "{{ vm_memory_mb | default(8192) }}"
        num_cpus: "{{ vm_num_cpus | default(4) }}"
      networks:
      - name: "{{ vm_network }}"
        start_connected: yes
        vlan: "{{ vm_network }}"
        device_type: vmxnet3
        type: dhcp
        domain: "{{ vm_domain }}"
      customization:
        hostname: "{{ vm_servername }}"
        orgname: Redacted
        password: "{{ winlocal_admin_pass }}"
        timezone: 255
      wait_for_ip_address: yes 
    register: vm
```

Variables:

```
vm_disk_datastore0: C6200_T2_FCP_3Days
vm_disk_size0: 80
vm_disk_type0: thin
vm_disk_datastore1: "C6200_T2_FCP_3Days"
vm_disk_size1: "50"
vm_disk_type1: "thin"
vm_disk_datastore2: "C6200_T2_FCP_3Days"
vm_disk_size2: "20"
vm_disk_type2: "thin"
vm_disk_datastore3: ""
vm_disk_size3: ""
vm_disk_type3: ""
```

Error:

```
{
    "_ansible_parsed": false,
    "exception": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/lib/awx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1568948672.23-135785453591577/AnsiballZ_vmware_guest.py\", line 113, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/var/lib/awx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1568948672.23-135785453591577/AnsiballZ_vmware_guest.py\", line 105, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/var/lib/awx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1568948672.23-135785453591577/AnsiballZ_vmware_guest.py\", line 48, in invoke_module\n    imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_vmware_guest_payload_6vidiw/__main__.py\", line 2396, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_vmware_guest_payload_6vidiw/__main__.py\", line 2385, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_vmware_guest_payload_6vidiw/__main__.py\", line 2008, in deploy_vm\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_vmware_guest_payload_6vidiw/__main__.py\", line 1690, in configure_disks\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_vmware_guest_payload_6vidiw/__main__.py\", line 1608, in get_configured_disk_size\nValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''\n",
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/lib/awx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1568948672.23-135785453591577/AnsiballZ_vmware_guest.py\", line 113, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/var/lib/awx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1568948672.23-135785453591577/AnsiballZ_vmware_guest.py\", line 105, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/var/lib/awx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1568948672.23-135785453591577/AnsiballZ_vmware_guest.py\", line 48, in invoke_module\n    imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_vmware_guest_payload_6vidiw/__main__.py\", line 2396, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_vmware_guest_payload_6vidiw/__main__.py\", line 2385, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_vmware_guest_payload_6vidiw/__main__.py\", line 2008, in deploy_vm\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_vmware_guest_payload_6vidiw/__main__.py\", line 1690, in configure_disks\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_vmware_guest_payload_6vidiw/__main__.py\", line 1608, in get_configured_disk_size\nValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''\n",
    "changed": false,
    "module_stdout": "",
    "rc": 1,
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error"
}
```

The idea being, if the variable isn't defined when the job is launched, it will be skipped by the vm_guest module.

Is this the best method? Is anyone able to suggest a successful way forward?

**Update**: Probably the best method would be to build the instance and then use vm_guest_disk to add additional disks using the method suggested below. This module is available in v2.8.

Our version of Tower is 2.7.9, so I'm going to use a more verbose method of multiple vm_guest calls via a disk_num variable:

Variables

```
num_disks: 0
vm_cluster: C6200_NPE_PC_ST
vm_datacenter: DC2
vm_disk_datastore0: C6200_T2_FCP_3Days
vm_disk_datastore1: ''
vm_disk_datastore2: ''
vm_disk_datastore3: ''
vm_disk_datastore4: ''
vm_disk_size0: 80
vm_disk_type0: thin
vm_disk_type1: ''
vm_disk_type2: ''
vm_disk_type3: ''
vm_disk_type4: ''
vm_domain: corp.local
vm_folder: /DC2/vm/ap-dev
vm_hostname: xyzvmserver.corp.local
vm_memory_mb: 16000
vm_network: C6200_10.110.64.0_24_VL1750
vm_num_cpus: 4
vm_servername: server05
vm_template: Windows2016_x64_AN_ESX_v1.1
```

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:

  - name: Launch Windows 2016 VM Instance - No additional Disk
    vmware_guest:
      validate_certs: no
      datacenter: "{{ vm_datacenter }}"
      folder: "{{ vm_folder }}"
      name: "{{ vm_servername }}"
      state: poweredon
      template: "{{ vm_template }}"
      cluster: "{{ vm_cluster }}"
      disk:
      - size_gb: "{{ vm_disk_size0 }}"
        type: "{{ vm_disk_type0 }}"
        datastore: "{{ vm_disk_datastore0 }}"
      hardware:
        memory_mb: "{{ vm_memory_mb | default(8192) }}"
        num_cpus: "{{ vm_num_cpus }}"
      networks:
      - name: "{{ vm_network }}"
        start_connected: yes
        vlan: "{{ vm_network }}"
        device_type: vmxnet3
        type: dhcp
        domain: "{{ vm_domain }}"
      customization:
        hostname: "{{ vm_servername }}"
        orgname: redacted
        password: "{{ winlocal_admin_pass }}"
        timezone: 255
      wait_for_ip_address: yes 
    register: vm
    when: num_disks == 0

  - name: Launch Windows 2016 VM Instance 1 Additional Disk
    vmware_guest:
      validate_certs: no
      datacenter: "{{ vm_datacenter }}"
      folder: "{{ vm_folder }}"
      name: "{{ vm_servername }}"
      state: poweredon
      template: "{{ vm_template }}"
      cluster: "{{ vm_cluster }}"
      disk:
      - size_gb: "{{ vm_disk_size0 }}"
        type: "{{ vm_disk_type0 }}"
        datastore: "{{ vm_disk_datastore0 }}"
      - size_gb: "{{ vm_disk_size1 }}"
        type: "{{ vm_disk_type1 }}"
        datastore: "{{ vm_disk_datastore1 }}"
      hardware:
        memory_mb: "{{ vm_memory_mb | default(8192) }}"
        num_cpus: "{{ vm_num_cpus }}"
      networks:
      - name: "{{ vm_network }}"
        start_connected: yes
        vlan: "{{ vm_network }}"
        device_type: vmxnet3
        type: dhcp
        domain: "{{ vm_domain }}"
      customization:
        hostname: "{{ vm_servername }}"
        orgname: redacted
        password: "{{ winlocal_admin_pass }}"
        timezone: 255
      wait_for_ip_address: yes 
    register: vm
    when: num_disks == 1

  - name: Launch Windows 2016 VM Instance 2 Additional Disks
    vmware_guest:
      validate_certs: no
      datacenter: "{{ vm_datacenter }}"
      folder: "{{ vm_folder }}"
      name: "{{ vm_servername }}"
      state: poweredon
      template: "{{ vm_template }}"
      cluster: "{{ vm_cluster }}"
      disk:
      - size_gb: "{{ vm_disk_size0 }}"
        type: "{{ vm_disk_type0 }}"
        datastore: "{{ vm_disk_datastore0 }}"
      - size_gb: "{{ vm_disk_size1 }}"
        type: "{{ vm_disk_type1 }}"
        datastore: "{{ vm_disk_datastore1 }}"
      - size_gb: "{{ vm_disk_size2 }}"
        type: "{{ vm_disk_type2 }}"
        datastore: "{{ vm_disk_datastore2 }}"
      hardware:
        memory_mb: "{{ vm_memory_mb | default(8192) }}"
        num_cpus: "{{ vm_num_cpus }}"
      networks:
      - name: "{{ vm_network }}"
        start_connected: yes
        vlan: "{{ vm_network }}"
        device_type: vmxnet3
        type: dhcp
        domain: "{{ vm_domain }}"
      customization:
        hostname: "{{ vm_servername }}"
        orgname: redacted
        password: "{{ winlocal_admin_pass }}"
        timezone: 255
      wait_for_ip_address: yes 
    register: vm
    when: num_disks == 2
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should build your vm with 1 disk, that you know for sure will always be there when you run the play, which you could make to be the first variable in this list:

```
vms:
  0:
    vm_disk_datastore: "C6200_T2_FCP_3Days"
    vm_disk_size: "80"
    vm_disk_type: "thin"
  1:
    vm_disk_datastore: "C6200_T2_FCP_3Days"
    vm_disk_size: "50"
    vm_disk_type: "thin"
  2:
    vm_disk_datastore: "C6200_T2_FCP_3Days"
    vm_disk_size: "20"
    vm_disk_type: "thin"
  3:
    vm_disk_datastore: ""
    vm_disk_size: ""
    vm_disk_type: ""
```

Since I don't know of a way that you can loop through sub module arguments to make them present or not, build your vm with the one disk you know for sure will be there.  Which mentioned above, for consistency, should be the first one in your list. Or you will need to rebuild the logic to drill into the list looking for a specific value that you can key in on with jinja filters like selectattr and map.

```
- name: Launch Windows 2016 VM Instance
    vmware_guest:
      validate_certs: no
      datacenter: "{{ vm_datacenter }}"
      folder: "{{ vm_folder }}"
      name: "{{ vm_servername }}"
      state: poweredon
      template: "{{ vm_template }}"
      cluster: "{{ vm_cluster }}"
      disk:
       - size_gb: "{{ vms.0.vm_disk_size }}"
         type: "{{ vms.0.vm_disk_type }}"
         datastore: "{{ vms.0.vm_disk_datastore }}"
      hardware:
        memory_mb: "{{ vm_memory_mb | default(8192) }}"
        num_cpus: "{{ vm_num_cpus | default(4) }}"
      networks:
      - name: "{{ vm_network }}"
        start_connected: yes
        vlan: "{{ vm_network }}"
        device_type: vmxnet3
        type: dhcp
        domain: "{{ vm_domain }}"
      customization:
        hostname: "{{ vm_servername }}"
        orgname: Redacted
        password: "{{ winlocal_admin_pass }}"
        timezone: 255
      wait_for_ip_address: yes 
    register: vm
```

Once its built, then use this different module to drill into adding additional disks

```
- name: Add disks to virtual machine
  vmware_guest_disk:
    hostname: "{{ vm_servername }}"
    datacenter: "{{ vm_datacenter }}"
    disk:
      - size_gb: "{{ item.vm_disk_size }}"
        type: "{{ item.vm_disk_type }}"
        datastore: "{{ item.vm_disk_datastore }}"
        state: present
    loop: "{{ vms }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "Disk {{ my_idx}} - {{ item.vm_disk_datastore }}"
      index_var: my_idx
    when:
      - item.vm_disk_datastore != ""
      - item.vm_disk_size != ""
      - item.vm_disk_type != ""
      - my_idx > 0
```

That will feed through a loop pulling that variable in from where ever you decided to define it, and then loop through that list of dictonaries pulling the values with the correct labels, but only doing so if they have a value (if leaving blanks in that list is something you plan on doing, if not, the when isn't even needed). This will also allow you to expand upward by just putting more items in the list without having to expand out your task.  If you need to edit the first task because you can't rely on list order, but need to key into a variable, then you need to make sure you make a change to the disks on the second task as well to omit using the disk added in the first task.

Also, the documentation on this module states that existing disks called called with this module will be adjusted to that size, and can't be reduced using the module, so if you want to avoid that, put in some data checks to compare the configured disk size to what is in your variable, so you can skip the task if it is going to be reduced (or if you just don't want an existing vm to be altered).

Comment: Thanks so much for the info. I tried your method and it populated the disk information as you'd expect, but the disks aren't actually created:

Comment: It looks like the vm_guest module tries to overwrite the initial disk 0 with disk 1    :                     
"msg": "Given disk size is smaller than found (52428800 < 83886080). Reducing disks is not allowed.", So basically your method is working as expected but for every additional disk in the dict, the vm_guest module thinks it's the main disk and will try and overwrite instead of adding an additional disk.

Comment: Oh, okay, I think that since its feeding the entire vmware_guest module through that loop, its taking from that list and trying to assign to that vm ONLY the disk in that iteration of the loop.  Let me edit my answer above with an alternative.

Comment: That's a really nice example of looping through the list. I started looking at the vm_guest_disk module as well, but it's new in 2.8 and the latest Tower is version 2.7.9   :)    . I'll come back and reference this code when we upgrade, it's very succinct. In the meantime I've just defaulted to having multiple  iterations of the module called via a disk_number variable,

Comment: Thanks very much for your assistance ebrewer, this is my first real use of stackoverflow and you've been really helpful. It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: No problem!  When you upgrade, please come back here and let me know if that worked.  I haven't personally used those modules myself so I am curious if that functions the way that I think it would.